# Is there a way to create a history of TCP/UDP sockets opened in android?

Tags: networking, logging, processes

Is there a log with this info? I know proc shows the ones opened at the moment but I need to see the ones that are already close

Comment: I don't think there is a log. Go for packet sniffing instead to create history. What information do you need e.g. port number, uid?

Comment: i want to know which socket is being used by a certain port, i want the inode of the network socket of a given port. tcpdump did not provide me this information. Maybe /proc/net/nf_confftrack may do it tho. My problem is that the socket is not displayed in /proc/net/udp but it is displayed in netstat plus as a udp connection in port 5353

Comment: thanks for the ss bin btw, unfortunaly there really seems to be no socket for these connections, since confftrack do display info about the connections and sockstats shows 0 sockets inuse. Confftrack displays a weird connection between a google ip with an "unavaliable" one: "100.93.255.67"

Comment: I wanted the sockets because with them I could write a code to search for the processes and kill them automatically

Comment: I'm not a programmer, so can't get into much details, but in my case results from `ss`, `netstat` and `/proc/net/{tcp*,udp*}` for ipv4, ipv6, listening and connected sockets, all are same as expected.

Comment: I actually found the problem, made the code i mentioned, still the payload is adapting

Comment: I did the final adaptations on my code. Closed all the doors the payload used to connect to other servers before it had a chance to readapt. From now I'll search for the payload itself and will stop making these confusing topics since i have more time and have my phone under control. Again, thank you very much for every comment/answer you gave me